# Error while executing gem ... (Errorno::EMSGSIZE)

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to install compass and Susy.
After installing ruby on Win8 and executing

**gem update --system**

I tried installing compass using

**gem install compass**.

But I'm getting following error:

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errorno:EMSGSIZE)
 A message sent on datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.

My command prompt version is 6.2.9000 (But I don't think that it makes any difference)
However, exactly same step on other machine works perfectly. Any thoughts?

reference:
http://compass-style.org/install/

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue, but only on Windows 8... Works mighty fine on Windows 7, Linux and OS X. But since I am required to use Windows 8 for that particular project, I'm kind of stuck...

Comment: Weird.. but for me it worked from a different network (office) but always displayed the same error from home network...

Answer (score 0):

You could check where the ruby is installed. 
If it is in `C:\ruby`, it could be due to the access on the folder.
You could run your terminal in `Administrator` mode so that it will 
have the needed access.

`Super key + x`
then select 
`Command prompt(Admin)`

Enter the following:

`gem update --system`

`gem install compass`